# Upload does not work with ajax. Work-around. Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, upload, submit

After much frustration, I've learned that uploading does not work with ajax.

I have two possible submit buttons. One is a typical submit, the other works next to the uploader.

My simple solution: just return before ajax is fired, thus making the page refresh in the usual way.

```
$("#html-upload").live('click',function(){
    return;
});
```

However, this doesnt seem to stop ajax from firing. It should not be that hard...so I was wondering where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return false to prevent the default action from occurring.

```
$("#html-upload").live('click',function(){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What we are going for is a page submit, cancelling ajax...this just stops the page from doing anything.

Comment: @Orangeman555 Well I thought that is what you wanted, you know that you can upload files now with ajax and there are jQuery plugins that simulate it for older browsers.

Comment: I wasn't sure about that! Is there a fairly lightweight solution to this? Its simply to upload a csv file.

Comment: @Orangeman555 I don't know if they're lightweight but you can check them out yourself. Here are some https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload http://fineuploader.com/ http://www.uploadify.com/